# закрыть последнюю вкладку с#?

Tags: c#, winforms, браузер

Необходимо закрыть последнюю открытую вкладку, не имеет значение в каком браузере на языке c#. Я вижу это так: мы выясняем какой браузер открыт, потом выясняем какие вкладки открыты, какая из них последняя, и закрываем её.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил задачу, правда не таким способом. Я просто сделал redirect запроса.